# How many overrides do you REALLY need in a struct in C#?

Tags: c#, struct, overriding, operator-keyword, implicit

I am making a wrapper for a "word" in an emulator project.  Its meant to put all my cast conversions all in one spot.  I was just about to start implement all the overrides for math functions (+,-,/,8, shift, etc.) When it occured to me that shouldn't all the implicit's take care of that?  Do I need to over ride >= and <= when I got > < and ==?

I thought I would ask this as while there are plenty of questions relating to how to create them, there aren't many on how much is enough.  Here is the code below:

```
public struct word_t
{
    ulong val;
    word_t(ulong val) { this.val = val; }
    public static implicit operator word_t(int a) { return new word_t((ulong)a); }
    public static implicit operator word_t(long a) { return new word_t((ulong)a); }
    public static implicit operator word_t(uint a) { return new word_t((ulong)a); }
    public static implicit operator word_t(ulong a) { return new word_t((ulong)a); }
    public static implicit operator int(word_t a) { return (int)a.val; }
    public static implicit operator long(word_t a) { return (long)a.val; }
    public static implicit operator uint(word_t a) { return (uint)a.val; }
    public static implicit operator ulong(word_t a) { return (ulong)a.val; }
    public static bool operator ==(word_t a, word_t b) { return a.val == b.val; }
    public static bool operator !=(word_t a, word_t b) { return a.val != b.val; }
    public static bool operator >(word_t a, word_t b) { return a.val > b.val; }
    public static bool operator <(word_t a, word_t b) { return a.val < b.val; }
    public override bool Equals(object obj) {
            return obj.Equals(val);
    }
    public override int GetHashCode() {
        return val.GetHashCode();
    }
    public override string toString() {
        return val.ToString();
    }
}
```

My gut tells me to "Trust the compiler" but my head always worries on how efficient it is.

PS I just realized I should override shifts because of the bit shifting of negative number problems, but for right now just imagine shifts just magically work like adds between uint and int.

Comment: Tsk tsk... I see a vulnerability to `NullReferenceException` in your `Equals` override.

Comment: Why not just use `UInt64` directly?  Why this custom type?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to move the idea of C++ `typedef`s into C#. My recommendation - don't. C# is not C++. Use a `ulong`, or re-structure your code.

Comment: p.s.  just on a semantic point, you overload operators, not override them.  If you use == between two references of type object, for example, you get object's == and not your == even if the object references refer to your type.

Comment: To be honest I was just playing around.  The idea is that I can make a type that can have its edeness changed on the fly but then started wondering if I was over programing for conditions I don't need.  Originaly its just being used to pass numbers between functions.

Comment: Ya:P  I saw that one @ChosPandion:P  just fixed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend this MSDN article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8edha89s(v=VS.100).aspx

It shows the operators you can overload and any catches.  You can overload `<=` and `>=` but they must be overloaded in pairs, as is true with `==` and `!=` as well.

The complex match operators +=, etc are available if +, etc. is overloaded, etc.

`>=` and `<=`, however, are separate.  That is, overloading `>` and `==` does not give you a `>=` operator implicitly.